# using "with" statement on multiple queries?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am attempting to delete duplicate rows from my table for example if my customer table contained the following:

```
first_name    last_name    email 
fred          wilford      wilford@xchange.co.uk
fred          wilford      wilford@xchange.co.uk
Damian        Jones        jones@xchange.co.uk
```

the ideal result should be the following:

```
first_name    last_name    email 
fred          wilford      wilford@xchange.co.uk
Damian        Jones        jones@xchange.co.uk
```

this should be fairly straightforward to do with an intermediary table created containing the duplicate rows before deleting the duplicates in the master table and lastly insert all rows in the intermediary table back into the master table. However I would prefer to remove the intermediary table and just use something like a with statement. 
consider the following example:

```
with dups as 
(
    select name,last_name,email from customer group by 1,2,3 having  
    count(*) > 1 
)
delete from customer
using
(
    select name,last_name,email from customer group by 1,2,3 having     
    count(*) > 1 
)b
where b.name = customer.name;
insert into customer
(
    select name,last_name,email from dups
)
```

the trouble is the final insert statement fails as "dups" is not recognised. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Common Table Expressions only exist for the main query - you'll need to use a temp table or table variable to use it in multiple queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also do it in this way:

*Schema:*

```
create table tbl (first_name varchar(50),
                  last_name varchar(50),    
                  email  varchar(50));
insert into tbl values
('fred','wilford','wilford@xchange.co.uk'),
('fred','wilford','wilford@xchange.co.uk'),
('Damian','Jones','jones@xchange.co.uk');
```

*DO this:*

```
CREATE TABLE temp (first_name varchar(50),
                  last_name varchar(50),    
                  email  varchar(50));
INSERT INTO temp SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tbl;
DROP TABLE tbl;
ALTER TABLE temp RENAME TO tbl;
```

*check:*

```
select * from tbl;
```

*result:*

```
first_name  last_name   email
fred        wilford     wilford@xchange.co.uk
Damian      Jones       jones@xchange.co.uk
```

Comment: nice, this way is a little cleaner!

Comment: Just for future reference, there are several things that may make this method _more_ complex.  You need to recreate indices, foreign keys, etc.

Comment: @DStanley you are right, 100% agree, plus 1 for your useful comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can [chain the CTE](http://www.depesz.com/2011/03/16/waiting-for-9-1-writable-cte/) if you want to:

```
WITH dups AS
(
    select name,last_name,email from customer group by 1,2,3 having  
    count(*) > 1 
),
del AS(
    DELETE FROM customer USING dups WHERE dups.name = customer.name RETURNING dups.*
),
ins AS(
    INSERT INTO customer(name,last_name,email) SELECT name,last_name,email FROM del RETURNING del.*
)
SELECT * FROM ins;
```

Comment: Can you do a DELETE or an INSERT in a CTE?

Comment: @DStanley Yes you can.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `WITH` clause, you could create `dups` as a temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE dups (name, last_name, email ) AS
(
    select name,last_name,email from customer group by 1,2,3 having  
    count(*) > 1 
);
```

Comment: yup that's what i have already, ok since i can't use with statements for multiple queries this will have to do

Comment: @godzilla: you _can_ use a CTE ("with statement") for multiple queries. See Jakub's answer